# Google Maps Shape Api GeoJson Not getting Value from php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps, geojson

I want to show map shape from *lat*&*lng*. Its working fine with static data but when I want to change it dynamically then its not getting *lat*&*lang*.

```
var lat = {{$lat}};
var lng = {{$lng}};
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
    map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([[{{$test}}]])});
```

Comment: var outerCoords = [{lat: 31.201673113556506, lng: 76.23963575810193}, {lat: 31.20109640095037, lng: 76.23962234705687}, {lat: 31.201153756911506, lng: 76.23906545341015}, {lat: 31.201612316570383, lng: 76.23900242149831},];

Comment: did you tried to `console.log(lat); console.log(long)` ? 
Also try this : 
`var lat = {!! $lat !!};
        var lng = {!! $lng !!};
console.log(lat);
console.log(long);`